# Return current web path in PHP

Tags: php, frameworks

Currently developing a PHP framework and have ran into my first problem. I need to be able to drop the framework into any folder on a server, no matter how many folders deep, and need to find that directory to use as a base URL.

For example, it currently works if I put the framework in the root of the server (http://cms.dev/), but if I were to put it in http://cms.dev/folder/ it does not work.

Comment: May I stress that I mean the WEB folder, i.e. http://cms.dev/folder/, not the server file path /home/dev/workspace/framework/

Comment: I know you are asking about the URL path here, but also keep in mind that URL paths and physical paths do not necessarily have a 1:1 relation. There are aliases (mapping /foo to /bar, for instance), URL rewrites, path info components, and whatnot. That said: check $_SERVER, esp. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and the like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four existing answers, but they all seem to deal with file paths, and you're asking about a base URL for web requests.

Given any web request, you get a bunch of keys in `$_SERVER` that may be helpful. For example, in your mock example, you might have the following:

- http://cms.dev/folder/ — `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == /folder/`
- http://cms.dev/folder/index.php — `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == /folder/index.php`
- http://cms.dev/folder/index.php/some/pathinfo — `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == /folder/index.php/some/pathinfo`
- http://cms.dev/folder/some/modrewrite — `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == /folder/some/modrewrite`

Thinking critically, how would you pull out the base URL for any given subrequest? In certain cases you can look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and strip off trailing elements if you know how deep in your hierarchy the request is. (For example, if your script is two folders deep, strip off the last two path elements.) When `PATH_INFO` or `mod_rewrite` are in use, things become less clear: as longer and longer URLs are provided, there is no clear indication where the paths end and the dynamic URL begins.

This is why WordPress, MediaWiki, phpBB, phpMyAdmin, and every application I've ever written has the user manually specify a base URL as part of the application configuration.

Comment: This is why WordPress, MediaWiki, phpBB, phpMyAdmin, and every application I've ever written has the user manually specify a base URL as part of the application configuration. << This was the thought I had a second ago. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

`__FILE__` is a magic constant that returns the entire path of the current script. Combine with [dirname](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) and add ".." appropriately. It's more reliable than `getcwd`, since it cannot change during execution.

You can then strip off the web root, to get the relative path to your script (should map to URL). There are many `$_SERVER` variables that have this information. I suggest using the file system to determine:

1. If your script is publicly accessible?
2. At which depth / URL prefix?

Then combine with your base URL. If your script's path ==
`/home/public/foo_1/script.php`
... and your $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ==
`/home/public`

Then you can rewrite your URL as `/foo_1/script.php`. You don't need the fully qualified URL, unless you want it. This technique works best if you execute it from a central location, like an autoloader.

Comment: I don't think that he wants the file name in the path tho.

Comment: That's what `dirname()` does... it strips off the file name and returns the "directory" name.

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing to define the root include path for files, but I need to define a base URL, that may not always be the web root. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In order to make urls work check the [base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp):

```
<base href="http://cms.dev/folder/" />
```

If the PHP file paths are the issue go with Pestilance's advice:

```
dirname(__FILE__) // returns the directory of current file
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the WEBROOT of your application based on your description.  The checked answer is, by far, the closest answer.

The easiest way to identify the webroot is to have it be user defined, as was mentioned by Annika and noted in a comment.

However, there is a bit of information that was overlooked:

If you are trying to identify the location of the webroot, which coincidentally is also the top level of your framework, then you could use something like this:

```php
$web_only_path = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

This will only work if your rewrite conditions are implemented correctly.

If they are in an **htaccess** file, no sweat.

However, if they are in an apache conf file.  Then they **must** be contained within a   container for the SERVER variable to store and return the proper information after working through the redirects when dealing with the SEO friendly URLs.

See:[SCRIPT_NAME and PHP_SELF with mod_rewrite in .conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377363/script-name-and-php-self-with-mod-rewrite-in-conf)

Comment: Well explained! Worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Theres a bunch of useful stuff available for things like this in the `$_SERVER` array. Do a `var_dump($_SERVER);` to see which element(s) of the array you need.

Comment: It sounds like it should have been a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
dirname(__FILE__);
basename(__FILE__);
print_r($_SERVER);
pathinfo('www/htdocs/index.html');
realpath('../../dir1/');
parse_url('http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor');
```

Comment: It is better to always give some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current path of the file you must use:

```
$path=getcwd();
```

This will return you if in windows for example `C:\blah\blah\blah` with no file name.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for the relative path.

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']
```

should do the trick.  The php.net site has good documentation on what is available to that http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Also, if you are ever curious about what else is there, and what the values are

```
<?php print_r($_SERVER);  ?>
```

will tell you more that you thought you could know.

Answer (score -1):

```
function GetCurrentWebDir() {
    $CurrentPath = substr(
        $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'], 0,
        strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL']) - strlen(
            strrchr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'], "\\")
        )
    );

    $CurrentFileName = basename(__FILE__);

    return substr_replace(
        $CurrentPath, '', -strlen($CurrentFileName),
        strlen($CurrentFileName)
    );
} 

echo 'current dir:'.GetCurrentWebDir();`

cp:/apps/PHP/testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest.php
fn:testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest.php
len:48
current dir:/apps/PHP/
```

Comment: To format this correctly, try putting 4 spaces before every code line.  After the 4 spaces, all special characters and spacing will be preserved.

Comment: Some explanation would be nice, although the code is nearly self-sufficient, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Use [`dirname(__PATH__)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) to fetch the parent directory path.