# SCRIPT_NAME and PHP_SELF with mod_rewrite in .conf

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

After moving this mod_rewrite from `.htaccess` to `apache2.conf` both `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` returns different values than else..

```
#   point all requests to index.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^                   /index.php [L,NS]
```

## example

URL:

```
http://domain.com/path/to/dir/
```

If the rewrite is in `.htaccess` then `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` returns `/index.php`

If the rewrite is in `apache2.conf` then `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` returns `/path/to/dir/`

How to get the relative path to doc root when `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` doesn't work?

Comment: Doesn't this question seems pretty similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30376779/3933332 ?

Comment: It was down voted so I deleted it......

Comment: Which Apache version are you using. If 2.4 then take special note about `REQUEST_FILENAME` from the official docs (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). Since 2.4 it matters where you use it. It behaves differently when defined in a virtual host (even default one) or inside a `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

To get the relative path to document root you could use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` eg usage:

```
define('APP_BASE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

or you could also use `realpath(dirname(__FILE__))` like so

```
define('APP_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

Hope this helps, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try using your rule like this and it really shouldn't matter where it's located as in the config or .htaccess. However make sure it's in a `Directory` directive if using the apache config. And restart apache for any config changes.

```
<Directory /var/path/to/root>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# point all requests to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</Directory>
```